# Try/except for check string in Python

Tags: python, try-except

I would like to use Try/ecept to check if a string is really a string. I made the following code:

```
nome = input('Name: ')
try:
    if not nome.isalpha() or nome == '':
        raise ValueError('Invalid!')
    else:
        print(f'Name {nome} valid.') 
except ValueError as e:
    print(f'Error: {e}')
```

But, I would like to do it without using the **raise** command, just try/except.

Can anyone help me? I thank you.

Comment: `try/except` requires something to raise the exception. There's no built-in function that raises an exception for non-alpha strings, so you have to raise it explicitly.

Comment: You would need to provide your own assertion method that raises internally. e.g. `def assert_isalpha_non_empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to trigger an exception without raising it yourself is to attempt something invalid, such as this:

```
nome = input('Name: ')
try:
    f = float(nome)
except ValueError as e:
    print('Is alpha')
else:
    print('Not alpha')
```

Here I try to convert the input to a float, and if there are any alpha characters in the value, it will raise the ValueError exception.